# smartGWT and Eclipse with WindowBuilder

Tags: eclipse-plugin, smartgwt, windowbuilder

I am using eclipse Helios with SmartGWT. If I start the WindowBuilder to design a GUI I always get this error message:

WindowBuilder supports only SmartGWT versions 2.2, 2.3. But 2.4 found.

I tried to use SmartGWT Version 2.2 by removing the 2.4 jars and adding the 2.2 jars.

However the message remained the same. If I use the GWT Designer  it works, but I do not get the SmartGWT controls, but just he usual ones fropm GWT.
I know that I had it working with SmartGWT 2.4 some ancient time but I have no idea what's wrong now...
Does anybody have an idea ? It would already help I could get the smartgwt controls to the WT designer but I have no idea on how to do that...

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow the instructions [here](http://idarkcell.wordpress.com/2012/08/26/gwt-designer-smartgwt-3-0/).

To summarize:

1. create a new java project with the gwt designer class found [here](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-designer/source/browse/trunk/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.SmartGWT/src/com/google/gdt/eclipse/designer/smart/parser/ClassLoaderValidator.java)
2. add the version numbers to the VALID_VERSIONS and VALID_VERSIONS_STRINGS in the code (eg, "3.0", "3.1", "4.0")
3. you'll have to add the following JAR's from your Indigo plugins folder:

   com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.SmartGWT_2.6.0.r37x201206111253.jar
   com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer_3.1.2.r37x201303061530.jar
   org.eclipse.wb.core_1.5.0.r37x201206111201.jar
   org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.7.3.v20120119-1537.jar
   org.apache.commons.lang_2.4.0.v201005080502.jar
4. close eclipse
5. open com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.SmartGWT_2.6.0.r37x201206111253.jar with 7Zip or something and replace the class files, which will be under your project bin folder

This seems to be working well with SmartGWT 4.0 also.  Unfortunately we're still stuck with using Indigo with WindowBuilder.  Juno might work for simple GWT, but I don't remember.  Kepler isn't working at all.